# Asp.net MVC 4 Database Query returning sql query.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to query my database to get a specific data from my database. however when I convert the query to string it doesn't return the select value, instead it returns the whole SQL Query in a string. I am stumped on why this is happening

```
public ActionResult StudiedModules()
    {
        Model1 studiedModules = new Model1();
        List<StudiedModulesModel> listModules = new List<StudiedModulesModel>();
            using (EntityOne context = new EnitityOne())
            {
                foreach(var module in context.StudiedModules){
                    studiedModules.School = context.ModuleDatas.Where(p=>p.ModuleCode == module.ModuleCode).Select(u=>u.School).ToString();
                    studiedModules.Subject = context.ModuleDatas.Where(p=>p.ModuleCode == module.ModuleCode).Select(u=>u.Subject).ToString();
                }
            }

            var data = listModules;

        return View(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ToString()` on an Entity Framework Linq query like that will in fact return the SQL Query. So as it's written, your code is doing exactly what you wrote it to do.

If you want to select the first result from the `IQueryable<T>`, then you need to call `First()` before your `ToString()`. So, try changing

```
studiedModules.School = context.ModuleDatas.Where(p=>p.ModuleCode == module.ModuleCode).Select(u=>u.School).ToString();

studiedModules.Subject = context.ModuleDatas.Where(p=>p.ModuleCode == module.ModuleCode).Select(u=>u.Subject).ToString()
```

to

```
studiedModules.School = context.ModuleDatas.Where(p=>p.ModuleCode == module.ModuleCode).Select(u=>u.School).First().ToString();

studiedModules.Subject = context.ModuleDatas.Where(p=>p.ModuleCode == module.ModuleCode).Select(u=>u.Subject).First().ToString()
```

There are a whole lot more methods available depending on what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to get a list, use `ToList()`, or as Uroš Goljat pointed out, you can get a comma-separated list of values using the `Aggregate( (a, b)=> a + ", " + b)` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have used First() - Which gives an error "Sequence contains no elements". So I used FirstOrDefault() which does not seems to get the correct values that I need, it seems to always get the first item within the database for all rows.

Comment: The "Sequence contains no elements" is the exception that `First()` throws when there are no results to your query. The difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` is that if there are no results from the query, `First()` will throw that exception, and `FirstOrDefault()` will return null.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but I have found when I add to my list within the foreach loop it overwrites all previous data with current one while adding itself. Do you know why this may occur?

Comment: You're not adding to your `listModules` instance of `List<StudiedModulesModel>`. You're just repeatedly changing your `studiedModules` instance of `Model1`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you were right, I needed to create a new studiedModules for each loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using Aggregate( (a, b)=> a + ", " + b) instead of ToString().

Regards,
Uros